# Internally diving of vectors

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Given the vectors
$$\begin{eqnarray*}A&=&i+j-k\\B&=&i-j+2k\\C&=&j+k\end{eqnarray*}$$

How do I find the position vectors which divide

1. BC
2. AC

internally in the ratio of 3:2?

Comment: What is (i)AC and (i)BC?

Comment: AC and BC are lines in vector form

Comment: and the "(i)"s?

Comment: @ChrisEagle I think these should be (i) and (ii). I have put in an edit...

Comment: How does one divide a line into a particular ratio?

Comment: Oh! That was typing error,thanks TooTone

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The ratio $3:2$ means that you divide each line into $3 + 2 = 5$ parts and go $3$ parts along the line. For part 1, to get $3/5$ the way along the line BC, you have to first get to B, and then go $3/5$ in the direction of $BC$. So you have to add the vector for $3/5$ of the direction of $BC$ to the vector for $B$.

You have given the vector for $B$ in the question. The vector for the direction $BC$ is the difference between the position of $B$ and the position of $C$, so it is calculated by subtracting the vector for $B$ from the vector for $C$.

Comment: I was upto sugesting that 3/5 is the ratio of externally dividing

Comment: @user83845 Great, hopefully you can see how to add B to 3/5 of BC and you've got the answer.

Comment: @JOSHUABANDA Please note if you find answers helpful you can accept (or upvote) them. I can see you've asked over 20 questions with some great answers (which took a lot more effort and are much better than my answer here) and only accepted / upvoted one time. It's nice if you're asking questions to participate by accepting and/or upvoting.